# how to interchange date oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

please i have a table like

```
customer_no   product_code
1345            001
1345            002
1345            003
```

i want a new table that will show me these details

```
customer_no  product_code, product_code
 1345          001             002
 1345          001             003
 1345          002             001
 1345          002             003
 1345          003             001
 1345          003             002
```

Comment: So you want the cartesian product of a self (cross) join? Are you sure you want a table with a static snapshot of that, not a view that stays up to date?

Comment: @Alex Poole - That doesn't look like a Cartesian product to me.

Comment: @mathguy - no, you're right of course, looking at it again - that would have nine rows. I was mostly asking for clarification of the requirement, clearly the lack of a description confused me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the desired output.

```
create yourNewTableName as (
   select t1.customer_no,
          t1.product_code,
          t2.product_code
   from yourOldTableName t1
   inner join yourOldTableName t2
         on t1.customer_no = t2.customer_no
   where t1.product_code != t2.product_code
);
```

Comment: how about   modifying  `inner join yourOldTableName t2 on t1.product_code != t2.product_code` and eliminating where condition.

Comment: ... or just changing the `where` to `and`, though that makes no practical difference. It's not unreasonable to think the real data has multiple `cusotmer_no` values and to assume the join should be restricted products within one customer, but it isn't clear in the question.

Comment: Thanks so much. info was so useful